# Why don't Python's assignment operators work if they're written with the equals sign on the left?

Tags: python

I've tried this, and I'd like to know more about why this doesn't work. `count += 1` works as intended, but `count =+ 1` does not.

```python
list = ["one", "two", "three"]
count = 0
for x in list:
    count =+ 1
    print(x)
    print(count)
```

The above example doesn't work properly. However, the one below does.

```python
list = ["one", "two", "three"]
count = 0
for x in list:
    count += 1
    print(x)
    print(count)
```

The intended output is to have it print each iteration all the way up to the number 3.

Just to clarify, this is not a question about why the Python language is designed this way, it is about how it manages to run without throwing an error. I was curious about what the proper syntax was.

Comment: Because the other way round is simply **not** an augmented assignment. It's actually `count = +1`, or just `count = 1` (as the unary `+` has no effect on a number that's already positive).

Comment: Python gets the syntax from C, which originally used `=+`, `=-`, etc. for augmented assignment, but switched to `+=`, `-=`, etc. in order to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: (That said, part of the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) is "There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it"; having two identical operators is in violation of that principle; that's more the kind of design decision Perl's [TIMTOWTDI](https://wordaligned.org/articles/timtowtdi-vs-tsboapooowtdi) philosophy leads to, and anyone who's tried to maintain someone else's Perl knows what kind of road that philosophy leads down).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you could have just mentioned that second comment without voting to close the question, I guess.

Comment: @icedwater, I could have, but the question _is_ off-topic for the reasons I linked.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My question was not about language design. I was wondering _why_ it was not working (and what the correct syntax was), not why the creators of Python chose to write the language that way.

Comment: One consequence would be that `count =- 1` is different from `count = -1`. Now, arguably that might be OK, but then: would `count=-1` with no spaces be valid? If so, what should it do?

Comment: @nearlystardust, "Why does [thing] not work if they're written with the equals sign on the left"? as part of your title _implies_ that you do in fact know that they do work with the equals sign on the right. I do suppose that that _is_ just an implication as opposed to an outright statement, but it's an odd choice of wording absent that prior knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's not proper syntax. The operator is `+=` ("plus equals"), not `=+` ("equals plus").

`count =+ 1` is the same thing as `count = (+1)`, where `+` is a unary operator on `1`.

Answer (score 1):

A little subtly, you can see the difference between `+=` and `=+` with [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) that `=+1` is interpreted as `= +1`

```py
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("count =+ 1")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (count)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("count += 1")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (count)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 INPLACE_ADD
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (count)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

It's clearer with `-` that `=- 1` is really interpreted as `= -1`

```py
>>> dis.dis("count =- 1")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (count)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("count -= 1")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (count)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 INPLACE_SUBTRACT
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (count)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how the syntax works, unfortunately. It's like if you wrote the words in a sentence in the wrong order, that would be wrong in an English class. Unlike in an English class, I understand what you mean, but since it's not *technically correct,* the Python interpreter does not.